# Bootstrap datepicker misbehaving

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have recently embarked on trying to do some front end work with Bootstrap and am finding it tricky.

There are two problems [here](http://home.technojeeves.com:8080/newjobform).

1. The calendar glyph appears under the date input. It's
   meant to be at the end of it and in the same 'line'
2. The picker is meant to be auto-closing but that's not happening

Any help would be welcome. The code of the misbehaving page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Add Job</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!--
        <script src="/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        -->
        <script src="/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <!--<link href="css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
        <link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                            autoclose: true,
                            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                            todayHighlight: true});
        </script>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Jobs</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/newjobform">Add Job</a>
                        </li>  
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">View</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/jobslastten">Last jobs</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/jobs">All jobs</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/jobsnext">Next jobs</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header" id="banner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-7 col-sm-6">
                                <h1>Add a Job</h1>
                                <form action="/addjob" method="post"
                                                             enctype="multipart/form-data" class=
                                                                                           "form-horizontal">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="form-group" data-provide="datepicker">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">
                                            Date</label>
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control">
                                            <span class="input-group-append input-group-addon"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></span>
                                            <!--
                                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            -->
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Place
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name=
                                                                          "place" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class=
                                            "col-lg-3 control-label">Amount</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name=
                                                                          "amount" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-3">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                                                                      name="button">Create</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552).

Comment: Please also read how to create a [mre]. In fact, you may want to read [ask] to cover all the bases.

Comment: It's easy to reproduce - you click on the link

Comment: ... I think you missed the "minimal" part. There's a lot of code there to reproduce a problem with a datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Font Awesome icon to float right while remaining inline, you need to wrap the text box and div of class `input-group-append` with a div of class `input-group`. I also removed the `input-group-addon` class, since that is outdated/replaced since Bootstrap 3.

Removing the `data-provide="datepicker"` attribute from the div of class `form-group` ensured that the date picker will auto-close.

I did notice you were loading the Bootstrap JS file before jQuery, so you'll want to switch the order since Bootstrap depends on jQuery.

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="datepicker">Date</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="datepicker" type="text" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" readonly style="background: transparent">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text" style="padding: 0.65rem 0.75rem; border-top-left-radius: 0; border-bottom-left-radius: 0"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks very good thanks. The only problem is that when I drop that code into the the `fieldset`, commenting out the other fields for the moment, the result is [very different](http://home.technojeeves.com:8080/newjobform). Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Just remove the `col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2` from the `form-group` div and the two outer divs. I was only putting those classes in so that it would look good on the Stack Overflow snippet viewer.

Comment: *... and the two outer divs* You mean the ones that were already in *my* code?

Comment: Actually I just removed the ones from your code and the picker is showing nicely, Unfortunately that's as far as it goes as it then crashes with an error in 'dropdown.js': *s.createPopper is not a function*

Comment: That may be related to you copying over the different versions of CSS and JS libraries I used in the code snippet. Those were only used for the example; you can replace those libraries with the original ones you had residing on your site.

Comment: Thanks, I've been toiling away at it. I decided to go for the ['manual'](https://getdatepicker.com/4/Installing/#manual) setup instructions. It's *still* impossible to know whether I have the right scripts installed. Despite following everything there, the datepicker now stubbornly refuses to show for me. There are no js errors showing